# How to slow down fade speed of nextGen gallery plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I'd like to modify the speed that the photos fade in and out of a basic slideshow of the NextGen gallery plugin for wordpress.  I know there is a setting to change how often the pictures change, however, I'd like to slow the actual fade down.

I'm guessing I need to modify the jQuery but I'm having a hard time finding the file where this speed is set.

Edit:  I am using version 2.0.40 if this matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>in, **`\wp-content\plugins\nextgen-gallery\nggfunctions.php`**,</strike>

after **`'fx:"'.$ngg_options['slideFx'] . '",' .`** (Line 129) ,

Add **`'speed: 1000,' .`**

This is where it generates the options for the cycle plugin.

## Update: For NextGen v2

The slideshow settings are saved in the database. So whatever you do in the files will have no effect. And the plugin is loading **`jquery.cycle.all.min.js`** by default. Editing **`jquery.cycle.all.js`** is not going to do anything. So edit the minified file,search for **`speed:1e3`** and change the value.

**NOTE:** Editing the **`jquery.cycle.all.min.js`** file will affect the site-wise transition speed. If you need individual speed setting for each slideshows, you need to customize the back-end to add another field from the code level.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This file is not located in that folder, I was able to find it in nextgen-gallery\products\photocrati_nextgen\modules\ngglegacy, but this line is not present in that file.  I posted my version of nextgen-gallery above if that matters.

Comment: It's in **`nextgen-gallery\products\photocrati_nextgen\modules\nextgen_basic_gallery\templates\slideshow\index.php`**, **`Line 193`**. This is where it laods the settings dynamically.

Comment: It seems like your solution should work but I can't get anything to change.  I added speed:5000, speed:'5000', speed:<?php echo_h(5000);?> to no avail.  I also tried modifying ./products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_gallery/static/slideshow/nextgen_basic_slideshow.js which has the same arguments and added speed to this and also tried adding it to both.  Nothing changes the speed of the fade on the photos.  Doesn't make sense to me.  I appreciate the help btw.

Comment: I've also noticed that if I modify values such as the timeout, when I view page source, none of these changes show up in the javascript that is inserted into the page.  I tried to make the timeout very large and it still changes photos at the same speed.

Comment: weird ! if you change the settings from the WP Admin, are they applied in the front-end ?

Comment: I tried adding a new gallery and was able to see my changes in the javascript, I had it at speed:9000 then speed:500,speedIn:5000, speedOut:500 and none of these setting had any effect.  The front end does register changes when modifying in wp admin.

Comment: Ok I found the problem. The slideshow settings are getting saved in the database. So what ever you do in the file will have no effect. And the plugin is loading **`jquery.cycle.all.min.js`** for default. So editing **`jquery.cycle.all.js`** is not going to do anything. So edit the minified file. Editing the **`jquery.cycle.all.min.js`** file will affect the site-wise transition speed. If you need individual speed setting, you need to add another field in the back-end to setup the speed. In the minified version, search for **`speed:1e3`** and change value.

Comment: If it's an option on the database, we can use [`pre_option_(option_name)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_option_(option_name)) together with [Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to fine-tune the value. I don't have NG, so cannot test.

Comment: This may work but I didn't need to try it.  I ended up modifying nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_gallery/static/slideshow/nextgen_basic_slideshow.js line 43.  I added speed:5000 as an option to the self.cycle function.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just tried your fix and that works as well, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but, since they use jquery cycle plugin, try to set speed option inside: jquery.cycle.all.js file in: products->photocrati_nextgen->modules->nextgen_basic_gallery->static->slideshow folder.

Options are at the bottom of the file:

```
speed:            1000,     // speed of the transition (any valid fx speed value)
```

line 1065.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Nice thought though.  These seem to be default settings and may be getting overridden somewhere else.

Comment: This would have worked if I modified the min.js file as shown above.